# How to change the button position

Tags: html, css

I want to change save button will be first then  prev button should be come

```html
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right mx-3"name="firstprevious"  onclick="mprev()" value="Prev">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right order-2"name="register"  value="Save">
```

Comment: add the missing CSS which is there in the code.

Comment: So switch between them maybe?

Comment: Am not using custom code

Comment: pure html and bootstrap class only am using

Comment: It is not clear why you can't just modify the HTML and put the 2nd line before the first line.

Comment: So you can't touch the HTML? I don't understand what's stopping you from moving the first HTML line to be the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right mx-3 prev" name="firstprevious"  onclick="mprev()" value="Prev">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left order-2 save"name="register"  value="Save">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{

        display: flex;
        }
        .save{
            order:1;
        }
        .prev{
            order:2;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `pull-left` to your save `button` and `pull-right` to your prev `button`. Please let me know if it's work. Thanks

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right mx-3" name="firstprevious"  onclick="mprev()" value="Prev">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left order-2"name="register"  value="Save">
```